# am set-debug-app not allowing run-as

Tags: android

I need to access files of an app that does not have debug flag set - I thought "am set-debug-app" should do the trick - unfortunately I get:

```
1|shell@android:/data $ am set-debug-app --persistent -w org.foo.bar    
shell@android:/data $ run-as org.foo.bar                         
run-as: Package 'org.foo.bar' is not debuggable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it doesn't have the permission in the manifest android:debuggable="true".

If your using gradle check:

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: I am aware of this - unfortunately this is not an option - I need to do this for an app that is already installed

Comment: Do you have the sources of the app? If you don't have the sources you can use apktool to extract the manifest and modify it http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: Yea - the app is my app - but I cannot reinstall - need to access files in the current state

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make `run-as` ignore the manifest of an installed app if it's marked as not debuggable; however, there is another way to access app data by using Android's built-in backup functionality.

First, create a backup of your app's data with

```
adb backup -f mybackup.ab com.my.app
```

Your device will ask for confirmation to start the backup; don't enter a backup password unless you want to make your life harder. This will create a `.ab` file containing just your app's data. Then, do

```
dd if=mybackup.ab bs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress | tar -xvf -
```

You may have to replace `zlib-flate -uncompress` with one of the following

```
openssl zlib -d
python -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))"
```

My Ubuntu's OpenSSL didn't support zlib; however, it came with `zlib-flate` installed, so I used that. You can also do it with Python if you want.

You should now be left with an `apps/` directory in your current working directory containing all of your app's data. If you want, you can edit the data, then restore it to the device using something like:

```
head -c24 mybackup.ab > edited.ab
tar -cvf - apps/ | zlib-flate -compress >> edited.ab
adb restore edited.ab
```

In my case, I wanted to edit a game's preferences file to replace an internal user ID with the one extracted from my jailbroken iOS device. However, since you say you have the application's source, if you want to edit the data (you only said you want to access it in the question) I'd recommend backing the data up, building and replacing your app with a debuggable version as per @isma3l's answer, then restoring the backup so that you don't even have to touch it.